# Best way to match minifigs and tell what set they are from?

Tags: minifigures, organisation

What is the best way to match minifig torsos, legs, heads? Is there a listing of all LEGO minifigures? I have a lot of minifigs with torsos and legs but have no idea which head goes with it.

Sometimes I can't even match torsos with legs :).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be to look through the Bricklink categories for [minifig torso assemblies](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=485) and [minifig leg assemblies](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=484). There are a lot of them, but once you find the part you are looking for, you can then learn what set it came from which should lead you to a couple of complete minifigs (click the part id then click the "View" link under "This Part Appears In" on the right).

You could also search through the [Minifig category on Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=&catType=M).

You can go through those categories by year if you know approximately how old the parts that you have are.

If you get stuck on something, feel free to post the picture in a new question here. I'm sure that someone will recognize it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Another useful tool is [goatleg.com](http://goatleg.com) which allows you to select torso and face characteristics to identify a minifigure e.g. torso color and print.  Face: glasses, facial hair, lipstick etc.

Answer (score 2):

I almost left a comment like "why hasn't someone written an app for that?"

[image: icon]

But then I googled and found there is an app for that ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.minifigure.theUnofficialLEGOminifigureCatalog), [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/unofficial-lego-minifigure/id486578707?mt=8)) and the folks who put it together have [books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1482528932) and they developed a [decent taxonomy](http://www.minifigure.org/taxonomy/) for sifting minifigs. The app, lets you search by part and then find the minifigs that include that part.  If you're not happy poking around BrickLink give this app a try.

[image: icon2]

I also tried the [Minifigs Collector for LEGO®](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lpeharda.lego.minifig)   app. If your goal was to get all of the minifigs in the various Series, Simpsons, etc. this would be great.  But it doesn't seem to let you search by parts and find which minifig that belongs to.